# Finding the count of the same matrix and ignoring NAs present in the matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix (V), which looks like this

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
[V1,]    37   15   NA
[V2,]    44   31   NA
[V3,]    NA   37   56
```

When [V1,] is compared to itself, the count is 2, as the two numbers are matched.

When [V1,] is compared to [V2,], the count is 0, because none of the numbers are matched.

Now each row of matrix V should be matched with itself (V) to get a count matrix like

```
     [,V1] [,V2] [,V3]
[V1,]    2     0     1
[V2,]    0     2     0
[V3,]    1     0     2
```

So, it is to count number of elements in a vector that are not NA..

To check the count between two same matrices (V==V)?

I have posted almost the same question here

[Finding pattern in one matrix to another matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941383/finding-pattern-in-one-matrix-to-another-matrix-in-r)

But I don't know how to do the same without counting `NA` in the matrices?

How do I do it using R?

Comment: In this question, its the same martix I am comparing with.. Means V==V

Comment: But the counts in the desired output don't make any sense

Comment: The count between V1 and V1 in the same matrix is 2 because 37 and 15 are the two numbers matched. Similarly V2 and V2 has highest count of 2 (44 and 31) because all the two digits are same, ignoring NAs.

Comment: Still I don't understand from where come 1 and 0. When comparing row by row the matrix to itself, the result is a vector. In your case, a vector of 2.

Comment: I have edited the post with a small explanation, to count only the non NA values in the matrix..

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option would be using the row index as 'X' and 'Y' arguments in `outer`, `Vectorize` the operation, `subset` the rows of 'V' based on the index, check whether the non-NA (`na.omit`) elements are present (`%in%`) in the rows that are compared, and get the `sum`. The output will be `matrix` and the `length` of that depends on the `prod(dim(V))`

```
 outer(1:nrow(V), 1:nrow(V), 
    FUN=Vectorize(function(i, j) sum(na.omit(V[i,]) %in% na.omit(V[j,]))) )
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3]
 #[1,]    2    0    1
 #[2,]    0    2    0
 #[3,]    1    0    2
```

#### data

```
  V <- matrix(c(37,44, NA, 15, 31, 37, NA, NA, 56), ncol=3)
```

Answer (score 4):

This gives the desired result:

```
mat2 <- V
for(i in 1:nrow(V)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(V)) mat2[i,j] <- sum(na.omit(V[i,]) %in% (na.omit(V[j,])))
}
> mat2
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    0    1
#[2,]    0    2    0
#[3,]    1    0    2
```

**data**

```
V <- matrix(c(37,15,NA,44,31,NA,NA,37,56),ncol=3, byrow=T)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the use the following code to get the count of matching elements in two rows excluding NAs...

```
length(na.omit(intersect(V[i,],v[j,])))
```

You can put this in a loop to generate a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

You can also go with a good old double-apply:

```
V <- matrix(c(37, 15, NA, 44, 31, NA, NA, 37, 76), 3, byrow = TRUE)
compare <- function(V1, V2) sum(na.omit(V1) %in% na.omit(V2))
apply(V, 1, function(V1) apply(V, 1, function(V2) compare(V1, V2)))
```